# Toolbar in Ext Js 4

Tags: extjs, toolbar

I am new to Ext Js. I am trying to create menu button and split button in the toolbar. here is my code

```
Ext.onReady(function(){
    new Ext.Toolbar({
        renderTo: document.body,
        items: [{
            xtype: 'tbbutton',
            text: 'Button'
        },{
            xtype: 'tbbutton',
            text: 'Menu Button',
            menu: [{
                text: 'Better'
            },{
                text: 'Good'
            },{
                text: 'Best'
            }]
        },{
            xtype: 'tbsplit',
            text: 'Split Button',
            menu: [{
                text: 'Item One'
            },{
                text: 'Item Two'
            },{
                text: 'Item Three'
            }]
        }]
    });
});
```

when i am running the above code in `ext-4.2.1.883` package, it is not showing the required toolbar. please help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're using the wrong xtypes, use:

- [button](http://docs-origin.sencha.com/extjs/4.2.1/#!/api/Ext.button.Button) instead of "tbbutton"
- [splitbutton](http://docs-origin.sencha.com/extjs/4.2.1/#!/api/Ext.button.Split) instead of "tbsplit"

Comment: thanks it works . I am using 'Learning Ext Js - Shea Frederick & Colin Ramsay _199' pdf as my reference but i think this book uses old packages of extjs. Could you please suggest me any good book for my learning purpose?

Comment: The PDF you mentioned seems to be from November 2008, so it probably refers to ExtJS 2 or 3. I'm afraid this will be outdated in many many ways, so I would not rely on that as a learning resource. A good place to start would probably be the [guides](http://docs-origin.sencha.com/extjs/4.2.1/#!/guide) in the official documentation. Also check out the [examples](http://docs-origin.sencha.com/extjs/4.2.1/#!/example), there are a lot of them.

Comment: thanks a lot for your suggestion. I would follow the official documentation then. :)